# Combine K-nearest neighbor with categorical embedding

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, k-nn

I've tried a few ways to do my multi-class classification. For categorical data, I used the [embedding technique](https://www.kaggle.com/astrus/entity-embedding-neural-network-keras-lb-0-748) with Tensorflow, which moves the entity closer with its similarity. This technique provides me with approximately 25%-30%, which is low.

For the numerical data, I used the KNN algorithm that gave me roughly 40% accuracy. I am wondering is there any way to "combine" these two techniques together to achieve a better result. For example, perhaps using the probability given by the KNN algorithm to form a layer concatenated with the embedding layer. Then, use the Dense layer to further train these data.

I've searched on the Internet. It's not the technique of ensembling, which averages the accuracy of each model. It's more like concatenating the layer together.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you label encode categorical variables and fed them to a neural network. If this is the case, you can try the following:

1. add the numerical variables
2. create and train an autoencoder
3. use the encoder part to map input to a vector space and perform k-nearest neighbor to it.

You can read the second method described in https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-credit-card-fraud-with-autoencoders-in-python-98391cace8a3 It uses a dataset with numerical variables only, but since you label encode categorical variables it applies in your case too.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried combining the numerical variables with embedding, but it didn't work well.

Comment: You are welcome. Have you tried one-hot encoding? I suppose that you have. I guess you have a lot of categories and/or unbalanced data. Maybe you should try something more domain-specific.

Comment: My data is kind of sparse, so I encoded it into numbers (in natural order) and concatenate them into one layer. For example, the keys of music are represented by 0-11, and the major & minor 
 are represented by 1, and 0.

Comment: Thank you!! I've got the idea of the autoencoder that it cut down the dimensions for visualization and some other analysis.